# Incorrect order in Rails scope

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I don't fully understand what rails scopes do. The rails query:

```
UserDesign.joins(:order_line_items)
     .where('order_line_items.created_at > ?',Date.today-1.month)
     .find(:all,
           :select=>'order_line_items.design_id as id,sum(order_line_items.quantity) as quantity',
           :group=>'order_line_items.design_id',
           :order=>'quantity desc'
     )
```

Returns the items:

```
 UserDesign Load (0.8ms)  SELECT order_line_items.design_id as id,sum(order_line_items.quantity) as quantity FROM "user_designs" INNER JOIN "order_line_items" ON "order_line_items"."design_id" = "user_designs"."id" WHERE (order_line_items.created_at > '2012-11-12') GROUP BY order_line_items.design_id ORDER BY quantity desc
+-----+----------+
| id  | quantity |
+-----+----------+
| 199 | 65       |
| 196 | 31       |
| 197 | 31       |
| 198 | 30       |
| 204 | 30       |
| 203 | 30       |
+-----+----------+
```

This is correct, but only two columns are included. The same query as a named scope yields:

```
UserDesign Load (0.7ms)  SELECT order_line_items.design_id as id,sum(order_line_items.quantity) as quantity FROM "user_designs" INNER JOIN "order_line_items" ON "order_line_items"."design_id" = "user_designs"."id" WHERE (order_line_items.created_at > '2012-11-12') GROUP BY order_line_items.design_id ORDER BY quantity desc
UserDesign Load (1.0ms)  SELECT "user_designs".* FROM "user_designs" 
+-----+-------+---
| id  | de... |...
+-----+-------+---
| 196 | aa... |...
| 199 | fd... |...
| 198 | as... |...
| 197 | as... |...
| 203 | Test  |...
| 204 | My... |...
+-----+-------+---
```

The SQL query is identical and all columns are returned, but they are not in the correct order. I would like to either

1. Use a named scope that is ordered correctly
2. wrap the plain query in a function but return all columns

Thanks!

EDIT:

For completeness, here's the named scope:

```
scope :popular_this_month, lambda{
     joins(:order_line_items)
     .where('order_line_items.created_at > ?',Date.today-1.month)
     .find(:all,
           :select=>'order_line_items.design_id as id,sum(order_line_items.quantity) as quantity',
           :group=>'order_line_items.design_id',
           :order=>'quantity desc'
     )}
```

Comment: "The SQL query is identical" -- I don't think so, it seems to be returning `SELECT "user_designs".* FROM "user_designs"`. Can you post your named scope so we can see if it is actually equivalent?

Comment: Good eye. I'm not sure what triggers that. Added the named scope I'm using to the original question. It's just the exact same query dropped inside a scope.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the first case you're passing a select option specifiying those 2 columns, so those two columns are what is returned. If you want more columns, list them (You can use table_name.* to get all the columns for a table)

In your second case you're calling `find` inside your named scope, which doesn't make any sense - a named scope is just a set of conditions and options, you shouldn't be actually doing the `find` in there. I suspect in that case it's ignoring all the options you're passing to find.

You want something more along the lines of

```
scope :popular_this_month, lambda{
     joins(:order_line_items).
     where('order_line_items.created_at > ?',Date.today-1.month).
     select(...).
     order(...).
     group(...)}
```

which should result as the same behaviour as the first example.

Comment: Of course. Yeesh. Thanks! The only remaining question is how to include all the columns. I can add columns to the select statement, but if I don't also add them to the group_by, I get get: ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::Error: ERROR:  column "user_designs.title" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function. (It's postgres) More of a SQL question, really.

Comment: Perhaps that's best asked as a separate question though.

Comment: Yup. Subqueries are the answer!

Answer (score 0):

One thing worth avoiding is mixing the old-school `find` syntax with the newer `where` et al.

```
scope :popular_this_month, lambda {
  joins(:order_line_items)
    .where('order_line_items.created_at > ?', Date.today - 1.month)
    .select('order_line_items.design_id as id,sum(order_line_items.quantity) as quantity')
    .group('order_line_items.design_id')
    .order('quantity desc')
}
```

I think that might be the problem.

Comment: Yup. Wasn't thinking. Thanks!